# Where is the $LANGUAGE environment variable might be set

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

I'm trying to set system language to `en_US.UTF-8` and leave such variables as `LC_TIME` set to my local time (`ru_RU.UTF-8`). I tried to use `locale-gen`, `localectl` utilities and edit /etc/default/locale, tried to use kde's settings manager but it always and up with this:

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
...
LC_ALL=`

I.e everything is OK except LANGUAGE variable: it's always `en_US:ru`. I'm sure it's not set by `~/.bashrc` and CO because if I set LANGUAGE in first line in `~/.bashrc` everything is OK, therefore LANGUAGE is set *before* `.bashrc`.

Even more: if I set LANGUAGE at the last line in `/etc/profile` it's still `en_US:ru`.

So it's set *after* /etc/profile but *before* `~/.bashrc`. Where is it might be?

OS: **Kubuntu 17.10**

```
$ uname -a 
Linux user-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: [The Bash Shell Startup Files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html)

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 0):

KDE also stores it's LANGUAGE variable in the `$HOME/.config/plasma-localerc` file:

```
[Formats]
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[Translations]
LANGUAGE=en_US:ru_RU
```